# How to preserve text in state for React function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a file,  *app.js*, which contains some React code. The code producess something like a rudimentary kanban board. Right now, the user can create a new div for the board, and then edit *or* drag the div into a column. However, the state is not preserved if the div has been edited before dragging across columns; the div contents will disappear.

I have tried editing the code in the returned div, modifying the *isContentEditable* property, but to no avail; the state is lost, and the entered content dissapears, leaving an empty div.

For reference, here is the code in a sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-feather-80261

All help is appreciated, total noob to front end development!

Comment: You could try to use React Context instead local state. Already, local state will be lost after `unmount` the component. It seems like how your `dnd` plugin works.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the useState hook for functional components, or look into Redux to implement global state!

Redux will allow you to have state that can be changed and used by multiple components.

Comment: Hi! that sounds cool, but I'm not sure where to begin there. Could you help to implement in the sandbox? ( for the record, I did not down vote your answer! As far as I know, your answer sounds good )

Comment: Haha, thanks! Brad Traversy on YouTube has great in-depth videos on both topic (React hooks and Redux). Redux can be alot to take in, but is amazing for larger projects.

Comment: If you're looking to use state across components I believe Redux is the best way and is used a ton in the industry.

Comment: I pulled up a react with redux book on oreilly, but in a crunch and have to get this done for my team asap! Thank you, and look forward to reading this : )